# iPhone Dev: UIAlertView Won't Show

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a button linked up to an IBAction called sendWO. This should be insanely simple, perhaps I'm missing some fundamental concept of the UIAlertView class. It's hooked up in my viewcontoller, and if I put in some NSLogs I know the button is calling the sendWO class correctly, it just doesn't show the alert. No warnings/crashes or anything like that. I've tried using delegate:nil , sender, self too, and removing the argument completely.

```
- (IBAction)sendWO:(id)sender
{
    NSString *theMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Thank you! We will call you     shortly at %@ to confirm.",choices.customerPhone];
    UIAlertView *alert = [alert initWithTitle:@"Thank you!" message:theMessage 
delegate:sender cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something simple:

You have to alloc the alertview

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Thank you!" message:theMessage 
delegate:sender cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];    

    [alert autorelease];
```

Comment: Blimey. Hour of my life WASTED.

Comment: @alukaiser It happens.  Sometimes its good to take a break and look at the code with fresh eyes